# Create duplicate form in Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: vb6

I have a form (for example, `abc.frm`). I want the duplicate form (for example, `xyz.frm`) of `abc.frm`. I don't want to create it again. So I used the **Save As** option. But it did not appear in **Project Explorer**.

To solve this I did as follows.

- I found **xyz.frm** in the source folder
- Opened it with *notepad*
- Changed form name from **abc** to **xyz**

But now I can not find the `abc.frm` file in **Project Explorer**.

If **Save As** is the correct option to create a duplicate form then ***What is the solution to keep both files?***. If not then ***How do I create duplicate form***?

Comment: You do know that you can create duplicate runtime instances of a form, with only one frm file? Just checking :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Save as" will save the form as the new name AND change the reference in the project to the new form file.

You can either:

1. Create form ABC
2. Save as ABC.frm
3. Change name to XYZ
4. Save as XYZ.frm
5. Re add ABC.frm to the project

or:

1. Create form ABC
2. Save as ABC.frm
3. Copy ABC.frm to XYZ.frm
4. Edit XYZ.frm to use the new name
5. Add XYZ.frm to the project

Comment: Great! It worked! I just closed the project and reopen it. Then added ABC.frm to the project. Now both files appear in the project.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to duplicate a frm within a project eg frma:

1. open the project folder
2. find the frma you wish to duplicate
3. copy the frma to and rename to frmb
4. open frmb in notepad
5. find and replace frma with frmb
6. open project
7. add a frm
8. select existing frmb

You now have it in project and can use it like any other form

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).